# Illegal State Exception while opening a SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, illegalstateexception

So, I have a class, named DatabaseHandler that inherits SQLiteOpenHelper. This class is incharge of managing a database that copies information from an online database to the cellphone. Now, the problem is that when I call its `getQuestionsCount()` method, which, as the name sugests, counts the number of items, it crashes. It crashes on the line that calls its `getReadableDatabase()` method. It tells me it has an IllegalStateException. What's going on?

Code on the activity that crashes. Checks if it already has questions stored for usage:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

if(db.getQuestionsCount() == 0)
    if(!isNetworkAvailable() || !canConnectToServer())
        return -2;
else
    if(!isNetworkAvailable() || !canConnectToServer())
        return -3;
```

parts of my DatabaseHandler class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
...
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_CATEGORY + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_ANSWER_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_ANSWER_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_ANSWER_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_ANSWER_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DATE_POSTED + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);

        db.close();
    }
    ...

    public int getQuestionsCount()
    {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); //<-- ERROR ON THIS LINE
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove db.close in onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_CATEGORY + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_ANSWER_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_ANSWER_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_ANSWER_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_ANSWER_4 + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DATE_POSTED + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
}
```

Your cursor is closed before return

```
public int getQuestionsCount()
{
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it probably would have caused an error later on still, but there still is an error in the line that says `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` That's where the error is coming from

Comment: I thought it had to be closed there. Thanks!

Comment: You should have a method open() and close() in DatabaseHandler and in your activity call open() in onStart and close() in onStop(). Unless the activity only use the database once then call open() and the method you want to call and then close()